# How can I get the almost last substring from "/" delimited string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I've got a string that consists of other strings delimited with "/" character (xxx...xxx/xxx/xxxx) how can I get the last and the almost last (the one before last) part with t-sql? It should probably be some combination of charindex() and right().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
declare @s varchar(50);
set @s = 'aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/ddddd/eeeee'

/* last one: */
select
    RIGHT(@s, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@s)) - 1)

/* penultimate one */
select
    RIGHT(
      LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@s))), 
      CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(
        LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@s)))
      )) - 1
    )
```

The "last one" is pretty straightforward, no explanation needed.

The "penultimate one" is essentially equal to the "last one", with all occurrences of `@s` replaced with:

```
LEFT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@s)))
```

which produces `'aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc/ddddd'`

To check whether there are enough slashes in the string for this expression to succeed, you could do

```
CASE WHEN LEN(@s) - LEN(REPLACE(@s, '/', '')) >= 2 
     THEN /* expression here */
     ELSE /* error value here */
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the '/' with a '.' and use [PARSENAME](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Ten_SQL_Server_Functions_That_You_Have_Ignored_Until_Now#PARSENAME).

Here's a SO answer using it: [Split String in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Comment: I didn't even know about `PARSENAME()`. Though it seems it can only handle up to four individual parts.

Comment: hey but it won't work properly if there are any other dots (".") in the string. and in this case there are. -1

Comment: @agnieszka: true, but I assumed that was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Parsename is only good when you have 4 or less delimited pieces....here is my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Piece(@string as varchar(1000),@delimiter as char(1),@piece as int)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @Items table (Piece int,Item varchar(8000) NOT NULL)
    declare @return varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @Item As varchar(1000), @Pos As int
    DECLARE @piecenum AS int
    SET @piecenum=1
    WHILE DATALENGTH(@string)>0
        BEGIN
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@string)
            IF @Pos = 0 SET @Pos = DATALENGTH(@string)+1
            SET @Item =  LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@string,@Pos-1)))
            IF @Item<>'' INSERT INTO @Items SELECT @piecenum, @Item
            SET @piecenum=@piecenum+1
            SET @string=SUBSTRING(@string,@Pos+DATALENGTH(@delimiter),1000)
        END
    SELECT @return=Item FROM @Items WHERE Piece=@piece
    RETURN @return
END
```

so:

```
select dbo.Piece('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q',',',10)
```

results in 'j'