# charindex() counts white chars in the end, len() doesn't in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to find an index of the last `/` character, but the problem is that
`LEFT(target, LEN(target) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(target)))`
doesn't work because the string in target column has a lot of space characters in the end and the `charindex` function includes the spaces, but `len` doesn't.

Is there any other function to replace one of them?

Comment: what version of sql server? Doesn't it suck that SQL Server doesn't have anything straightforward to do such a thing? OR am I being ignorant?

Comment: its funny that it shows a related question that you asked yesterday. Here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248512/t-sql-getting-almost-last-substring-from-delimited-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RTRIM function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) trims the trailing whitespace.

```
LEFT(target,
     LEN(target) - CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(RTRIM(target))))
```

Comment: If you are interested in counting the white space this solution doesn't help. As RBarryYoung [suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1253423/692942) use `DATALENGTH()` instead but always remember to divide it by 2 if working with unicode data as it counts bytes not characters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, LEN() does not count trailing whitespace.  Use DATALENGTH instead, but be aware that it counts bytes, not characters, so if you use it on NVARCHAR() values, you'll have to divide it by 2.