# Does the LEN() function internally apply TRIM()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dooes the SQL `LEN()` function internally `TRIM()` the data prior to calculating length of the string?

Example:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(MAX), @b VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @a = '12345 '
SET @b = '12345 7'

SELECT @a, LEN(@a)
-- 12345    5

SELECT @b, LEN(@b)
-- 12345 7  7
```

Both `@a` and `@b` have 7 characters. `@a` has 5 numeral characters and two spaces at the end.

When copying both the results from the Results window, I can see that both variables have a length of 7 chars. But when trying to find the length of the variables using `LEN()` it differs. The same thing happens while storing data in a table with a `varchar` column.

Comment: If you want the length of the string including spaces at the end or at the beginning you can use `DATALENGTH` instead

Answer (score 5):

It excludes the **trailing** blanks

According to [LEN (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)

"*Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.*"

Also similar questions about

[Why does t-sql's LEN() function ignore the trailing spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428311/why-does-t-sqls-len-function-ignore-the-trailing-spaces)

[LEN function not including trailing spaces in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025585/len-function-not-including-trailing-spaces-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

`LEN` excludes trailing blanks.

I would use

```
LEN(REPLACE(expr, ' ', '_'))
```

This should work with `varchar` and `nvarchar` and also with strings containing special unicode control characters. The `DATALENGTH` function suggested at other places will not yield the correct result in all cases.

You could also use

```
LEN(expr + '_') - 1
```

But the resulting string might exceed the maximum text length in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "trim" the source per se (meaning it doesn't *alter* it) - but it does exclude training blanks:

From [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx):

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.